# How can I update the flexi page without going to record page > edit page

Tags: lightning-experience

I have accidentally added a modal dialog (lightning component) into my lightning flexi page which I can't close (Actually, I don't know how to close it)

So I find it hard to click the setup button > edit page. Since there is always a modal dialog on the page. Is there any other place where I can edit the page?

Comment: You can hide the modal and the overlay with css using your browser dev tools and then navigate in the setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit pages from the Lightning App Builder (Setup > Build / User Interface > Lightning App Builder). You can set to it from either Lightning or Classic, so long as you can get to the Setup screen. Once there, simply find the broken page, and you can modify it.